# Get all products with their custom options in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am trying to show all the products with their custom options in a magento grid in admin panel.
I can not figure out how to do this. I have to show products in grid and their custom options , if a product has 2 custom options then another row will show up for both custom options.
All custom options are of drop down types.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

Here Below code using custom options get and select option to easily set

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

    foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal):
                   foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
                          echo $valuesVal->getId().' '.$valuesVal->getTitle();
                    }
    endforeach;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have to show the collection in the UI grid along with all the products

Comment: you can use also grid render 
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-use-grid-renderer-in-magento-2user-renderer-in-magento-2grid-renderer-magento-2/

Comment: yes renderer is an option but then it will be an issue to manage the custom options in multiple rows

Comment: if you are used render then easily to manage select option

Answer (score 0):

Declare `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option` in construct of your class.

Try following snippet:

```
protected $productOption;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $productOption
){
    $this->productOption = $productOption;
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
/**
 * [$_product Product Object]
 */
$customOptions = $this->productOption->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
if (!empty($customOptions->getData())) {
    foreach ($customOptions->getData() as $option) {
       print_r($option); // You will get option data here

    }
}
```